# Launch Daemons in MAC OSX

Tags: macos, startup, launch-daemon

I have written a daemon is MAC OS 10.8.

I copied the Unix executable file to startup items.

I have created a .plist file which has  Label,KeepAlive flag set to YES and progrrammArguments array's Item0 as /Libray/StartupItems/updaterDaemon.

I want this daemon to run as root when a system start up hence I copied it into startupItems,but the daemon does not get launched.

Please tell what I am doing wrong or What I need to do to launch and run this daemon on system/machine start up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing startup items and launchd jobs. A startup item is a special kind of bundle with certain properties. This is [deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/StartupItems.html) technology. You want to write a launch daemon. How to do this has been answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/820/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-tutorial-for-writing-from-scratch-a-cron-style-lau). There are also some [launchd GUI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19740/is-there-a-gui-for-os-x-launchagents/94078#94078)s out there which can help you to achieve your goal.

Should your job still fail make sure to set `StandardErrorPath` and `StandardOutPath`. Check those files to find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can read exhaustive overview of macOS daemons here: https://medium.com/@alkenso/macos-daemonology-d471fd21edd2

For detailed configuration of daemon.plist, use `man launchd.plist` or refer the article: https://www.real-world-systems.com/docs/launchdPlist.1.html